# Remove a bunch of directories from one location based on a list of directories in another location?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have two directories in totally different places in the filesystem:
/path1/dir1/*
/path2/dir2/*

dir1 has a list of subdirectories and dir2 has a similar list of subdirectories, some of which are also in dir1

I'd like a command that can use a list of the subdirectories that are currently in dir1 and if they exist in dir2, delete them.

I was able to output a list of the subdirectory names using the find command and sed together like this:

find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed -e 's\^/path1/dir1///g' and that will output:
subdir1
subdir2
subdir3

but I don't know how to then feed that into a command to delete (recursively) those subdirectories from another location. Do I need to use awk or xargs or something?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
cd /path1/dir1; find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf /path2/dir2/{} \;
```

Replace the "rm -rf" with "echo" to see what directories it will delete before trying it :-)

The "-f" option prevents errors if the directory doesn't exist

Some versions of find (GNU?) also have "-execdir". You can use it like this:

```
find /path1/dir -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -execdir rm -rf /path2/dir2/{} \;
```

Comment: Your `find` solution is very elegant and avoids the use of the slow shell, but the problem with it is the following in the POSIX spec:

`If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change. `

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in path1/dir1/*/
do
    rm -rf path2/dir2/"$(basename dir)"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using find to locate the dirs and piping to awk:

```
find /path1/dir1/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d |awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{system("echo rm -rf /path2/dir2/"$NF);}'
```

remove the "echo" in the system() call when you are sure the command is behaving properly.